# Difference between .NET Framework Developer Pack and Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .Net Framework 4?

Tags: .net, sharpdevelop

I am installing SharpDevelop 5.

Below the download link, it recommends I install both, `Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 Developer Pack` and
`Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4`.

On the Microsoft download page, it says the `SDK` for `Windows 7` download has compilers, headers, libraries.

I was under the impression that .Net libraries and compiler was contained in the regular .Net Framework from the Windows Updates and .Net Framework Developer pack.

What is the difference between these two installers and why are both needed?

Comment: SDK7 is ancient, it does not have the reference assemblies of recent .NET Framework editions.  Like 4.5.1.  Which is what the "developer pack" contains.

Comment: So it isn't needed? Would I be just fine installing .Net 4.5.1 or 4.6.1 developer pack?

Comment: You need it, the SDK contains several build tools that are not included with the .NET install.  Following the vendor's install instructions is always wise.